# When using SSO what can take over the session timeout in Salesforce setup?

Tags: single-sign-on

Sessions expire automatically after a predetermined length of inactivity, which can be configured in Salesforce from Setup by clicking Security Controls. The default is 120 minutes (two hours). If you make an API call, the inactivity timer is reset to zero.

We have Salesforce set fo 30 minutes.

So when you try and login and your session is still valid (you were last active within 30 minutes in your case) it's not surprising that you get the same session ID back.

Each time you call into Salesforce your session will be valid for 30 minutes from that point.

We installed SSO/Ping Federate on our network for Salesforce login. We are trying to figure out where the timeout session takes over. It no longer is 30 minutes but seems to last between 1 and 1 1/2 hours? Did the VPN, Ping Federate, or something else take over the application login and session timeout?

Comment: Are you calling into Salesforce using the API? and are you making a "Login" call after every 30 mins and using the same session id for subsequent calls? or are you only calling into Salesforce every 30 mins?